# Compare two columns onEdit and if match, color the newly added into color

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a verification of attendees to some event by scanning a QR code and adding its information into a sheet.
on QRstuff.com its possible to generate and import a QR scan into an online Excel file.
The sheet has a list of names, and I want the newly added scan, onEdit, to be compared to the already existing list in the sheet, right after added, and the new name to be painted in some color.

I've tried to change some code I've found on SO, and couldn't make it work.

```
 var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var lr = sh.getLastRow()// get the last row number with data
 var data = sh.getRange(1,1,lr,1).getValues(); // get only columns C.D,& E.  Starting at row 2 thur the last row
 //var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();// read all data in the sheet
 for(n=0;n<data.length-1;++n){ // iterate row by row and examine data in column D
 //  if(data[n][0].toString().match('dsf')=='dsf'){
 if(data[8][1].match(/Pavel/i)){ //changed to find either upper or lower case dfs or with other text in string.
  data[n][2] = 'w';
  data[n][0] = '1.2'};
  }
  sh.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[3].length).setValues(data); // write back to the sheet only Col C,D,& E
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things you may want to fix:

```
var data = sh.getRange(1,1,lr,1).getValues(); // get only columns C.D,& E.  Starting at row 2 thur the last row
```

This will get the data in column A from row 1 till the last row.

The comment says you want the data in columns C, D and E from row 2 till the last row. To do that, change the code to

```
var data = sh.getRange(2, 3, lr - 1, 3).getValues();
```

Similarly, when you post the data back to the sheet

```
sh.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[3].length).setValues(data); // write back to the sheet only Col C,D,& E
```

This will post it to the range starting from A1 and down to the last row in column C.

To write to columns C, D and E starting from row 2, use:

```
sh.getRange(2, 3, data.length, data[3].length).setValues(data);
```

While iterating through the data:

```
for(n=0;n<data.length-1;++n)
```

This will ignore the last line of data.

To iterate through all lines, use:

```
for (var n = 0; n < data.length; ++n)
```

I'm not clear on what this line does

```
if(data[8][1].match(/Pavel/i)
```

But just wanted to point out that as you iterate through all the lines of data, this will always check the 9th line (data[8]).

If you need to check the value for that line in column B, then you need to change it to data[n][1].

Of if you are only checking a specific line, you can check it once outside the loop and store the result instead of checking it repeatedly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've changed after your comments to this ```function onEdit(){
 var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var lr = sh.getLastRow()// get the last row number with data
 var data = sh.getRange(1,1,lr,1).getValues(); // get only columns from colum A.
 for (var n = 0; n < data.length; ++n)
 { 
   if(data[7][1].match())
 { 
  data[n][2] = 'w';
  data[n][0] = '1.2'};
  }
  sh.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
 }```

Comment: and now I have another question. I want to compare the content of column A to the existing content of column H. if the data in A is present in H, can the cell in A be colored to green?

Comment: data[7][1] will give you the data in cell B8.

This is because data[0] is row 1;

And so data[7][0] is cell A8.

So to compare the contents of columns A and H, use
if ( data[n][0] == data[n][7] )  {

}

To set colours to the cell backgrounds based on whether or not there is a match, see [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setBackgrounds(String))